# UITableView in UITabBarController gets 10 px shift down on rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I have a UITableView inside UITabBarController, when the starting orientation for the TableView is Landscape there is no problem, but when the Starting Orientation is Portrait it get shifted down by 10 px after rotating, please see Images,

Before Rotating:
[image]

After Rotating:
[image]

The gray 10 pixel rect is shown between the Status and the UINavigationController.

Any help would be so much appreciated.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, but it seems has nothing to do with what i was facing but i tried everything and this finally did the job.

Here what i used to do to:

#### Before

I used to load My UITabController through an IBOutlet connected from on XIB and load it as follow:

```
[window addSubview:self.oTabNavigationViewController.view];
```

#### Now

I Removed my UITabViewController from the XIB and load it from the application delegate as follows:

```
self.oTabNavigationViewController = [[TabNavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabNavigationViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];

[self.oTabNavigationViewController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen ]applicationFrame]];
[window addSubview:self.oTabNavigationViewController.view];
```

Thanks all for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Open the XIB in interface builder, click on the tableview, open the inspector, choose the View Size tab (third from the left). Under Autoresizing (not size and position) you will see a white rectangle, with a black rectangle inside, and bunch of arrows and lines that will effect that way the view reacts to resizing of the superview (correct me if i'm wrong). Basically, play around with those :) I might be wrong but i think that in your case, you should select both autoresizing arrows (the 2 inside the small black rectangle) and the lines to the top and to the left of it (outside of the black rectangle).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response but my XIB Autoresizing settings already conforms your settings.

Comment: Is your app hiding the status bar? And is the status bar enabled in the xib in the settings of the top level UIView?

Comment: No i don't hide the status Bar, and as you see in my screen shots my View is UITableViewController and i made couple of attempts removing the status bar or keeping it did not solve the problem, i am so appreciated for responding to my comments.

Comment: Is the toolbar in the screenshot a subview of your UITableview then? That might cause some weird behaviour, maybe that's the problem. Try instead of using a UITableviewController subclass subclassing a UIViewController that implements UITableviewDelegate and UITableviewDatasource. On the view controller's xib you should have a UIView which should have the tableview and toolbar, both direct subclasses of the UIView. and set the tableview's delegate and datasource to your view controller.

Comment: No the tool Bar is added though Pushing controls on the Navigation Controller, the weird case that if i start my application landscaped the problem don't occur, it happen only if i start Portrait.